# Nested wrapper functions are returning Promise<Promise<T>>

Tags: typescript, promise, es6-promise

I have a wrapper function (`doesPromiseyThings`) that takes a thunk and returns the thunk's return value inside a Promise. I'd like to create another wrapper that handles creation of the thunks - creates a function that takes the same parameters as the original, returns the Promise-wrapped type of the original, and passes the function through `doesPromiseyThings` when it's executed.

When I try to do this, passing in a function that returns a promise, my returned types are all `Promise<Promise<T>>`, which TypeScript complains isn't the same as the `Promise<T>` I'm trying to assign the return value to.

```js
async function foo(param: number) {
    return param;
}

function doesPromiseyThings<T>(fn: () => T): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.resolve(fn());
}

function wrapper<T,U>(fn: (...args: T[]) => U) {
    return (...args: T[]) => doesPromiseyThings(fn);
}

const wrappedFoo = wrapper(foo);
// (...args: number[]) => Promise<Promise<number>>

const output = wrappedFoo(1);
// Promise<Promise<number>>
```

I tried unwrapping the Promise in the wrapper's return value, but I get type errors doing that:

```js
function wrapper<T,U>(fn: (...args: T[]) => U): (...args: T[]) => Promise<U extends Promise<infer V> ? V : U> {
    return (...args: T[]) => doesPromiseyThings(fn);
}
/*
Type '(...args: T[]) => Promise<U>' is not assignable to type '(...args: T[]) => Promise<U extends Promise<infer V> ? V : U>'.
  Type 'Promise<U>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<U extends Promise<infer V> ? V : U>'.
    Type 'U' is not assignable to type 'U extends Promise<infer V> ? V : U'.(2322)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here by doing this, but I was able to get this code snippet working.

Also, you weren't passing the args while wrapping either..

Also, try looking into decorators for these kind of things:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

```
async function foo(param: number) {
    return param
}

function doesPromiseyThings<T>(fn: (args: any) => T, args: any): Promise<T> {
    const promise = new Promise<T>((resolve) => resolve(fn(args)))
    return promise
}

function wrapper<T, U>(fn: (args: T) => U) {
    return (args: T) => doesPromiseyThings(() => fn(args), args)
}

const wrappedFoo = wrapper(foo)

const output = async () => {
    console.log(await wrappedFoo(1))
}

output()
```

For ..args

```
function foo(param: number) {
    return param
}

function doesPromiseyThings<T>({ fn }: { fn: (...args: any[]) => T }): Promise<T> {
    const promise = new Promise<T>((resolve) => resolve(fn()))
    return promise
}

function wrapper<T, U>(fn: (...args: T[]) => U) {
    return (...args: T[]) => doesPromiseyThings({ fn: () => fn(...args) })
}

const wrappedFoo = wrapper(foo)

const output = async () => {
    console.log(await wrappedFoo(1))
}

output()
```